# Task.WaitAll on a list of TransformBlock

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I currently have a number of transform blocks running in a sequence a action task then does a wait all for these transform tasks come to completion however it looks very messy and as i add more transform blocks its going to get worse.

```
 Action<Task> postOrderCompletion = t =>
            {
                Task.WaitAll(EDIFACT_96A_Processor.Completion, EDIFACT_97A_Processor.Completion, ErrorProcessor.Completion);
                SetForProcessing.Complete();
            };
```

Is there a wait i can wait all for a list of transform blocks to complete?

```
var listOfTransformBlocks = new List<TransformBlock<Invoice_Base[], Invoice_Completed>>();
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(listOfTransformBlocks.Select(b => b.Completion).ToArray())`?

Comment: Are your blocks linked? Why don't you just propagate the completion?